# {longtable} Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (1): `c' used.

Tags: errors, longtable

I'm new to Latex and really learning the nuances as I go.

My document was compiling fine, until all of a sudden, it wasn't. I'm using the {longtable} command. I get the following error message:

```
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (1): `c' used. ...}{Here, we are inputting g(x) into f(x).}
```

at this point in my code:

```
& & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Here, we are inputting g(x) into f(x).} \\
```

My code as a whole looks something like:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
...other stuff....
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{ m{4.5em}|c|c } 
...table stuff...
& & \\
& & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Here, we are inputting g(x) into f(x).} \\
```

Again, it was working perfectly fine, but then suddenly it started flagging errors out of seemingly nowhere.

What is Latex trying to tell me?

Comment: In the code fragment you show have used `l` for left alignment but the error message says you had used `1` (one) by mistake.

Comment: unreleated but are you sure that shouldn't be `$g(x)$ into $f(x)$` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Answer or close?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. close, just typo (I voted)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because simple 1/l typo